# How to design class that will provide me a bunch of questions and answer?

Tags: java

This is what I want:

For example on some way to store 30 questions, code pick random one, show it to user, give him a three option for answer that he get, if he pick right one program continue.

Basically, I have in my mind how to make this, but I think so far its not on good way, because If I want to store many question there will be a lot of code that will repeat, and I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

I created `Class` like this:

```
public class QuestionsLevelEasy {

String question;
int answer;

public QuestionsLevelEasy(String question, int answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}
// getter - setters
```

Method to return random question and let user choose answer:

```
public static void randomQuestionAndUserGuess() {
    QuestionsLevelEasy q1 = new QuestionsLevelEasy("Who is best NBA player?", 1);
    QuestionsLevelEasy q2 = new QuestionsLevelEasy("Who is best Football player?", 2);
    QuestionsLevelEasy q3 = new QuestionsLevelEasy("Who is best Hokey player?", 3);
    QuestionsLevelEasy q4 = new QuestionsLevelEasy("Who is best Tennis player?", 4);
    List<QuestionsLevelEasy> givenList = List.of(q1, q2, q3, q4);
    Random rand = new Random();
    QuestionsLevelEasy randomElement = givenList.get(rand.nextInt(givenList.size()));
    System.out.println("Here is your question, guess it right and continue: ");
    System.out.println(randomElement.getQuestion());

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    for (QuestionsLevelEasy questionsLevelEasy : givenList) {
        if (questionsLevelEasy.getAnswer() == choice) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Correct!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, its easy to understand so far. Things that I' missing right now is to provide a user option menu to choose answer. So for example user get `Who is best NBA player?` show him 3 answers related on that question.

I tried to find some examples on how to achieve this but nothing useful so far, plus when I try to google `How to create a list of questions and answers in Java` google return me `PDF` of questions and answer from Java :D

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75421475/642706) is good in that it suggests defining a custom class to contain your question *and* answers.

I would take it a step further by (a) defining your custom class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) since you have no need for [setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) ([immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)), (b) representing the correct answer as the [ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_numeral) within the list of the offered answers, and (c) using [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E)) methods for simplicity.

Define the class in one brief line.

```
public record Question( String ask , List < String > answers , int solutionOrdinal ) { }
```

Use `List.of` to build some data.

```java
package work.basil.example.quiz;

import java.util.List;

public class QuestionsRepository
{
    // For now we hard-code some data.
    // Later we could re-implement by reading CSV text files or hitting a database.
    List < Question > fetchQuestions ( )
    {
        return
                List.of(
                        new Question(
                                "Best programming language" ,
                                List.of(
                                        "C" ,
                                        "C++" ,
                                        "Java"
                                ) ,
                                3
                        ) ,
                        new Question(
                                "Best beer" ,
                                List.of(
                                        "Pilsner" ,
                                        "Porter" ,
                                        "IPA"
                                ) ,
                                2
                        ) ,
                        new Question(
                                "Non-existent color" ,
                                List.of(
                                        "Magenta" ,
                                        "Red" ,
                                        "Blue"
                                ) ,
                                1
                        ) ,
                        new Question(
                                "Best programming font" ,
                                List.of(
                                        "Pragmata by Fabrizio Schiavi" ,
                                        "Menlo by Jim Lyles" ,
                                        "Comic Sans by Vincent Connare"
                                ) ,
                                1
                        )
                );
    }
}
```

Declare a `Quiz` class to present the questions and answers to the user.

Notice how we pass the content, the list of questions, to the constructor. This addresses the design principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The `Quiz` class is dedicated to *presenting* a quiz, not generating its content. The `QuestionsRepository` class is dedicated to retrieving a set of questions, not presenting to the user.

Also notice how we use `Collections.shuffle` to randomize the order of elements in our list of questions. This approach is simpler than picking questions randomly while tracking remaining questions.

```java
package work.basil.example.quiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz
{
    private final List < Question > questions;

    // Constructor
    public Quiz ( final List < Question > questions )
    {
        List < Question > q = new ArrayList <>( questions );  // Make a modifiable list from a possibly unmodifiable list.
        Collections.shuffle( q ); // Randomize the order of elements in this list.
        this.questions = List.copyOf( q );  // Generate a new unmodifiable list.
    }

    public void present ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Here is your quiz, with " + this.questions.size() + " questions." );
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        for ( Question question : questions )
        {
            System.out.println( "--------|  Question  |-------------------------------------" );
            System.out.println( question.ask() );
            System.out.println( "Answers:" );
            int ordinal = 0;
            for ( String answer : question.answers() )
            {
                ordinal++;
                System.out.println( ordinal + " | " + answer );
            }
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();
            if ( choice == question.solutionOrdinal() )
            {
                System.out.println( "Correct." );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "Incorrect. Solution is: " + question.solutionOrdinal() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, we write a class to run our app. This class harnesses our other classes.

```java
package work.basil.example.quiz;

import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        QuestionsRepository qRepo = new QuestionsRepository();
        List < Question > questions = qRepo.fetchQuestions();
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz( questions );
        quiz.present();

        System.out.println( "Demo done. " );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Here is your quiz, with 4 questions.
--------|  Question  |-------------------------------------
Non-existent color
Answers:
1 | Magenta
2 | Red
3 | Blue
1
Correct.
--------|  Question  |-------------------------------------
Best programming font
Answers:
1 | Pragmata by Fabrizio Schiavi
2 | Menlo by Jim Lyles
3 | Comic Sans by Vincent Connare
1
Correct.
--------|  Question  |-------------------------------------
Best programming language
Answers:
1 | C
2 | C++
3 | Java
3
Correct.
--------|  Question  |-------------------------------------
Best beer
Answers:
1 | Pilsner
2 | Porter
3 | IPA
3
Incorrect. Solution is: 2
Demo done.
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your questions with possible answers and the correct answer in a file, for example a csv.

```
Question; Choise1; Choise2; Choise3; Answer
For which NBA Team did Michael Jordan play for 13 years? Chicago Bulls; Washington Wizards; Dallas Mavericks; Chicago Bulls
...
...
```

Expand your question object with the fields question, choices and correct answer.

```
public class QuestionsLevelEasy {

    String question;
    List<String> choices;
    String answer;

    public QuestionsLevelEasy(String question, List<String> choices, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    // getter - setters
}
```

Read the file and create `QuestionsLevelEasy` objects and show the user the question with the choices and compare the user input with the correct answer.